# Trigger Click Event using Class Name on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, minify

Hi I have gone through the several thread i could not able to find correct solution

So here is my issue

I need to initiate a Click Event on a class name When page loads. 
When click even occurs a color palette displays

Here is a demo : http://demo.weibsites.com/index.php/product/test-product/

When user Clicks on Layer1 or Layer2 color palette displays

Need Solution: TO make color palette display onPageLoad

Here is a quick Code

```
  <div class="fpd-list ui-sortable">
     <div class="fpd-list-row" id="1438484105689">
        <div class="fpd-cell-0" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: visible;">
          <i></i>
        </div>

        <div class="fpd-cell-1" style="opacity: 1; pointer-events: visible;">
        Layer1
        </div>

        <div class="fpd-cell-2"
            <span class="fpd-lock-element fpd-tooltip tooltipstered">
            <i class="fpd-icon-unlocked"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) yet?

Comment: yeah tried this 

$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".fpd-list .fpd-list-row .fpd-cell-1").trigger('click');
    },10);
});

Not worked

Comment: you don't need document.ready/ nor do you need setTimeout. just put the trigger line after you assign click event to the class

Comment: @SivaKumar Are you sure the handlers are set on the what you are trying are trying to trigger?

Comment: @prodigitalson yes you can check the URL i have provided on Clicking on Layers Corresponding Color Palette Opens.

Comment: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/t61dx40e/), your code should look something like that

Comment: @NocturnalPenguin Let Me check this !!

Comment: @NocturnalPenguin This is the click event function on class .fpd-list-row can you help me to the trigger click event and its min.js file

 'k.on("click",".fpd-content-layers .fpd-list-row",function()
{
if($(this).hasClass("fpd-locked"))return!1;
for(var a=r.getObjects(),b=0;b<a.length;++b)
if(a[b].id==this.id)
{r.setActiveObject(a[b]);break

}})'

Answer (score 0):

put this line after you assigned the click event, tried it in console, works without a problem

```
$(".fpd-list .fpd-list-row .fpd-cell-1").first().trigger('click');
```

Comment: yes ! it worked on console but when i add that code in the Js file it not firing may i am wrong :( 

k.on("click",".fpd-content-layers .fpd-list-row",function(){

$(".fpd-list .fpd-list-row .fpd-cell-1").first().trigger('click');

if($(this).hasClass("fpd-locked"))return!1;

for(var a=r.getObjects(),b=0;b<a.length;++b)

if(a[b].id==this.id){r.setActiveObject(a[b]);break
}
});